# Rigify, Model detaches from rig when animating

Tags: rigify

I used rigify to rig a robot model I downloaded. When I click the play button in the animation window the model shrinks and detaches from rig (see pictures).
I am new to Blender so thank you in advance for your response.[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file (delete some parts of the mesh if necessary)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me a few times. It is likely because vertex groups in the mesh are misnamed (wrong bones connect to certain areas), particularly left and right being mixed up.

The shrinking thing is strange. Did you make this animation yourself? Is it possible you animated the mesh's scale by accident?

There is a possibility that some physics simulation is also set up on the robot and is conflicting with the armature.

If none of this helps, please share the blend file, then someone will look at it and be able to tell you exactly what's going on.